# Which stock is better to sell in a falling market? The first bought or the most expensive one?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing

The stock market in the US has been falling with consecutive losses. What is the best stock to sell:

- when everything was bought 9 months, less than a year ago?
- when everything was bought more than a year ago?

In order to reduce:

- losses
- taxes

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I am thinking of selling in order fund the down payment and closing costs for a place. I would not have considered selling anything otherwise.

Comment: Remember "Buy low, sell high"? You are talking about doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding future gain or loss on the remaining shares, it makes no difference what the cost basis of the shares to be sold now is, as long as the number of shares is the same.  Nor does the purchase date matter either. For example, you bought 100 shares at $24 and 100 shares at $25.  If you sell 100 shares now, you will be left with 100 shares and either way, you'll make $100 for every $1 that the share price rises and you'll lose $100 for every $ that share price drops.

However, it will matter when it comes to taxation.  If underwater, selling the higher cost basis shares will provide a larger capital loss (limited to $3k per year).  If profitable, selling the higher cost basis shares will minimize the capital gain.

Lastly, long term capital gains have a lower tax rate so that should also be considered when choosing which shares to designate for sale.

Comment: How does selling the lower cost basis shares provide a larger capital loss? If I have 2 shares with cost bases of 100 and 150 and the current price is 40, wouldn't I get the larger loss from selling the $150 stock?

Comment: Regarding taxation, does that mean that if the loss is 10,000, I only get to claim $3000 and the remaining $7000 is gone and can't be claimed in future years?

Comment: I also added an edit as to how I landed on this situation

Comment: Yep, that was a typo.  Edited and fixed.  Losses offset gains.  After that, you get to deduct only $3k per year unless you have Trader Tax Status which is only available to full time, high volume traders.  So a $10k loss would take 4 tax years to claim, assuming that you do not have subsequent offsetting gains.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best stock to sell:
>
> ```
> when everything was bought 9 months, less than a year ago?
> when everything was bought more than a year ago?
> ```

also:

> thinking of selling in order fund the down payment and closing costs for a place.

This assumes that you have enough shares of a single company to get the money you want, or that you will be selling a combination of investments to get the money you want.

You state you want to reduce losses and taxes, but the question is also what do you see happening in the next few months/years? Which do you want to still own next year?

Losses aren't taxed. Therefore there is no tax factor. If your losses in 2022 will be more than $3,000 then you will not be able to deduct all the losses this year, but will have to spread it out over several years

Make sure that you factor in any shares that you purchases from any dividends you earned since you owned the shares. They will have a different cost basis.

Comment: Could you clarify your second last sentence?

Comment: If you received dividends and used them to purchase additional shares, those shares will have a different cost basis then the ones purchased with the initial investment. Also factor in shares bought at different times.